# Is it possible to pass a file as argument in mongodb insertMany()?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to know if there is any way in which I can pass a .json or .txt file as a parameter for a mongodb insert function using a JS script and loading it from the cmd.
For example, I want to be able to do something like

- In cmd: load(script.js)
- scripts.js would have something like: `db.products.insert("products.json")`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask a question that is more likely to get answered. Code should be not included  as an image. It is best to include it as a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we have the information we need to be able to help.

Comment: Why do you want to pass a file to `insertMany` method? What are you trying to achieve? You can use `mongoimport` command-line tool to import documents from a JSON file into a MongoDB collection. `insertMany` doesn't accept a file as a parameter: See [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly.

If the products.json file contains an array of objects, you could modify it slighty so that it is a javascript file that assigns the array to a variable.

```
var docs=[
 ... objects ...
]
```

Then you could use the `load` function to evaluate that file, and then use the docs with insertMany:

```
load("products.js");
db.products.insertMany(docs);
```